# OpenLayers Overview Map Control in Geoserver

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to add OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap() to group of layers (geotiff with shp file) in Geoserver. Is there any way to automatically add this control to every map which I would like to display from Geoserver by OpenLayers? There already are some default control buttons like scale or navigations. I assume that this will require some changes in *js or other file in Geoserver, please let me know which one it will be.

Comment: Are you talking about adding a control to the OpenLayers viewer in GeoServer?

Comment: Thank You for the answer John! Yes, I would like to add OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap to every map which I want to view in Geoserver by using OpenLayers.

Comment: You need to modify the OpenLayersMapTemplate.ftl file in wms/src/main/resources/org/geoserver/wms/map/OpenLayersMapTemplate.ftl and also, possibly, the wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/map/OpenLayersMapOutputFormat.java. I can't find much documentation on it.

Comment: Thank You very much for your advice! I'll try it and I will let You know if it works.